# Doppler Shift of a source that oscillates in Simple Harmonic Motion

Tags: experimental-physics, doppler-effect, experimental-technique

I am doing an experiment where I am measuring the Doppler Shift of an object that is oscillating in Simple Harmonic Motion.

***Experimental Setup***

- Take a spring and attach it to the ceiling
- Attach a buzzer to the end of the spring
- Set a microphone a few centi-meters below the maximum amplitude of the oscillation
- Oscillate the spring system and record the Doppler Shift on the microphone
- Repeat the experiment starting with the buzzer playing 300Hz and move up to a 1000Hz

However, I am running into problems when I record the frequency and analyse it (Which I am doing on Audacity). I came up with a mathematical formulation for this experiment, which does not match up with my experiment at low frequencies of the buzzer playing. I have no idea why this is happening as I know that my mathematics is correct.

Does an experiment like this not work at lower frequencies? If anyone has done an experiment like this any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Reflected sound from the ceiling might be the culprit...

Comment: Maybe...But I don't think so because I suspended it quite lower than the ceiling and it works quite well for frequencies like 1500Hz